# How to install Supergroup.js as Ember-cli dependency

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'd like to use [Supergroup.js](https://github.com/Sigfried/supergroup) in ember-cli (I use `ember-cli:0.2.7` and `ember 1.12.1`). Supergroup is implemented as an Underscore or LoDash mixin, so author suggests to include `lodash` dependency first.

After adding dependencies to `bower.json`:

```
//bower.json
"dependencies": {
  //...
  "lodash": "^3.9.3",
  "supergroup":"1.0.13"
}
```

I got error:

```
Could not find module lodash
// at supergroup.js:  "_ = require('lodash');"
```

As a workaround I forked `supergroup`, removed following code fragment from `supergroup.js`:

```
// if (typeof require !== "undefined") {
//     if (typeof underscore !== "undefined" && underscore === "underscore") {
//         var _ = require('underscore');
//     } else {
//         var _ = require('lodash');
//     }
// }
```

and it worked.

I'm not good in understanding how ember-cli dependencies work, so I'd like to understand what's going on and what's proper way to install Supergroup.js without brute force patching, adding `dependencies` in `bower.json` (or may be in `package.json`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it works with `ember-browserfy`.

```
 npm install --save-dev lodash
 npm install --save-dev supergroup

 //where needed
 import _ from 'npm:supergroup';
```

and nothing in `bower.json`, `Brocfile.js` and `.jshintrc`!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to include lodash in your **bower.json**, it's already specified as a dependency in supergroup. All the author meant (I'm assuming) is that it should be included first as far as javascript is concerned.

This is actually a much more complex issue than I had in mind. Basically **supergroup.js** attempts to figure out if it's being used with AMD modules or not using the code you commented out.

ember-cli converts ES6 modules into AMD modules through babel. So when supergroup.js is loaded it detects `require` and thus expects `lodash` to be available. It isn't!

Because ember-cli can't presently handle something referred to as anonymous AMD modules:

```
define([], function() {
    return lib;
});
```

Which is what lodash does when it's figuring out what environment it's in and how to expose itself.

I tried compelling lodash into making itself available in a format that could be picked up by supergroup.js, but I don't think it's currently possible without changing either ember-cli, lodash or supergroup.js. I would really suggest you just use your edited version for now. There's various related issues causing this.

References:

- https://github.com/artsyca/ember-cli-lodash/issues/3
- https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2949
- http://blog.abuiles.com/blog/2014/10/03/working-with-javascript-plugins-in-ember-cli/
- https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2177

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to make another correction to supergroup.js code, so that this correction can be proposed as reasonable pull request for supergroup's author? (My correction obviously can't be proposed)

Comment: @Artych The problem isn't really with supergroup.js (primarily in any case), it's with lodash integrating into ember-cli. I think you're better of leaving the issue until ember-cli has moved away from bower altogether and the issue of anonymous amd modules have been fixed, then maybe revisit it. There are unfinished attempts by both lodash and ember-cli to fix the ES6 module issue right now.

Comment: Ember CLI now supports Anonymous AMD modules. https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#managing-dependencies